# Values of a continuous and twice differentiable function using intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[0, 1]$ whose first and second derivatives, $f$ and $f''$, respectively, exist at any point in $(0, 1)$. In addition, we have
$f (0) = 0$, $f (x_1) <x_1$, and $f (1)> 1$,
for $0 <x_1 <1$. Show that there exists:

(a) $x_0 \in (x_1, 1)$ such that $f (x_0) = x_0$;

(b) $x_3 \in (0, x_1)$ such that $f '(x_3) <1$;

(c) $x_4 \in (x1, 1)$ such that $f '(x_4)> 1$;

(d) $x_5 \in (x_3, x_4)$ such that $f '(x_5) = 1$;

(e) $x_6 \in (x_3, x_4)$ such that $f'' (x_6)> 0$.

Comment: This might be tricky to answer since we don't know the "result[s] on the numerical functions seen in the course." What have you covered? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $$g(x) = f(x) - x$$
Since $f$ is continuous, $g$ is also continuous
Now, $$g(x_1) = f(x_1)-x_1 < 0$$
Also, $$g(1) = f(1) - 1>0$$

By the Intermediate Value theorem $\exists x_0 \in (x_1,1)$ such that $g(x_o)=0$
$\implies$ $f(x_0) = x_0$

Since the derivative of $f$ exists, we can apply Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem (LMVT) to the interval $(0, x_1)$
LMVT states that $\exists x_3 \in(0,x_1)$ such that 
$$f'(x_3) = \frac{f(x_1)-f(0)}{x_1-0}$$
But $f(0) = 0$
$$\therefore f'(x_3) = \frac{f(x_1)}{x_1}$$
But $f(x_1) < x_1$ $\therefore$ $\frac{f(x_1)}{x_1} < 1$
$$\therefore f'(x_3)<1$$

We can again apply LMVT to $(x_1,1)$ to get (c)
$\exists x_4 \in (x_1,1)$ such that
$$f'(x_4) = \frac{f(1)-f(x_1)}{1-x_1}$$
But $f(1) > 1$ and $f(x_1)<x_1$ $\therefore -f(x_1)>-x_1$
$$\therefore f(1)-f(x_1)>1-x_1$$
$$\therefore \frac{f(1)-f(x_1)}{1-x_1} = f'(x_4)> 1$$

We can apply Intermediate Value Theorem to $(x_3,x_4)$ to get (d).
To get (e), apply LMVT to $f'(x)$ in $(x_3,x_4)$. By LMVT,
$\exists x_6$ $\in (x_3,x_4)$ such that 
$$f''(x_6) = \frac{f'(x_4)-f'(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}$$
But $f'(x_4)>1$ and $f'(x_3)<1$
$$\therefore f'(x_4)>f'(x_3)$$ 
Hence we get the desired result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, for the question c, I tried to apply LMVT, but I just can prove that f'(x4) > 0, can you be more precise please

Comment: I made the appropriate changes. Please check if it is satisfactory now

Comment: Alright, for the (e) part, I m trying to get the second derivative of f(x6) but then I stuck there where I don't know if f(x3) > f(x4)